# R Shiny - dataset load in a first chunk doesn't exist in a second chunk ...?

Tags: r, shiny, r-environment, user-environment

I have a strange error in a shiny app I built with the library **learnr**. An error "*Object not found*" about an object I just loaded and just visualized (meaning the object exists no ?)

Although I don't have a reproducible example, some of you will maybe understand what is creating the error :

- I have a first chunk {r load} that loads a dataset. There is no error here, I can even visualize the dataset (screenshot below)
- Then I have a second chunk, where I would like to manipulate the dataset. But it tells me **dataset doesn't exist !** How it could be possible, I just visualized it one chunk before ?! ...

[image]

I don't understand how a dataset could be exists in a chunk, and not in another. Does it mean the dataset isn't loaded in the global environment ? Is it a problem with the learnr library ?

Maybe someone will have an idea, or something I could test. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
The problem is about the environment/workspace. In the first chunk, even if I load the dataset, it is not store in the environment. I tested the function `ls()` in a second chunk, and it tells me there is no object in the workspace. The loaded dataset is not here, I don't know why ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, shiny doesn't store any data. You have to pass it manually from one chunk to other as follow (only adding the code snippet from `server`):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$heat <- renderPlotly({
    Name<-c("John","Bob","Jack")
    Number<-c(3,3,5)
    Count<-c(2,2,1)
    NN<-data.frame(Name,Number,Count)
    render_value(NN) # You need function otherwise data.frame NN is not visible
    # You can consider this as chunk 1
  })

  render_value=function(NN){
   # Here your loaded data is available
     head(NN)
   # You can consider this as chunk 2 
    })  
  }           
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You can find full code here: [Subset a dataframe based on plotly click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443854/subset-a-dataframe-based-on-plotly-click-event/54444378#54444378)

**OR**

Create `global.R` file as suggested here and follow this URL: [R Shiny - create global data frame at start of app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054287/r-shiny-create-global-data-frame-at-start-of-app)

Comment: @demarsylvain: I have added an answer based on my understanding. If I am wrong then please let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I will test the "global.R" (to load the dataset in this file). I will let you know if it works.